# Ionic: GoogleAnalytics plugin Error: ts: Cannot find name 'GoogleAnalytics'

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic-plugins

I am trying to use Google Analytics plugin on Ionic, the documentation code is not applicable as when I use:

```
constructor(private ga: GoogleAnalytics)
```

the editor says "ts: Cannot find name 'GoogleAnalytics'"
however it can see some Object GoogleAnalyticsOriginal instead which compiles but does not work (gives error on runtime).

These are system specs
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 4.5.0

Ionic Framework : 
ionic-angular 3.9.2

@ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.1

Cordova:
cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.1.2 (cordova-lib@8.1.1)

Cordova Platforms : android 7.1.4

Cordova Plugins : cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 1.1.1, (and 15 other plugins)
System:

NodeJS : v10.13.0 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)

npm : 6.5.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You installed the latest `@ionic-native/google-analytics` (v5+).

Then you should import `GoogleAnalytics` from `@ionic-native/google-analytics/ngx`

```
import { GoogleAnalytics } from '@ionic-native/google-analytics/ngx';
```

Or else install `@ionic-native/google-analytics` with v4+, then you can import `GoogleAnalytics` from `@ionic-native/google-analytics`

```
import { GoogleAnalytics } from '@ionic-native/google-analytics';
```